# Can Factory Girl be used to efficiently create persistent test data/artifacts for use in other tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I primarily write UI Automation with Selenium, and in order to write really independent, parallel-execution-ready tests, I need my tests to create and destroy any test data that they need (such as user accounts to log in with) dynamically at run time.

I would usually hope for a good API that I could leverage in the setup step of my UI Automation test cases to create these pieces of test data, but I'm told that an upcoming project won't have an API or any publicly accessible services that could do such a thing.

I am told that the developers are using Factory Girl in their Rails tests to create things like this, and I'm hoping that I can make use of the work they've already done to create similar data. We want to avoid having to write and maintain our own database injection scripts, or having the UI Automation actually try to create this test data via the UI, etc.

So! Assuming that we wrote some custom rspec tests that were actually utilities for creating test data, and were able to trigger them remotely and on-demand from outside the system under test, can Factory Girl be invoked in such a way that it doesn't wipe out the database before it runs, and also doesn't destroy the data that it creates? Since the developers are already making sure that Factory Girl is creating appropriate data for their tests, it seems like a great idea to piggy-back on that and use it for creating persistent test accounts, if we can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to turn RSpec's `transactional_fixtures` off. Update your spec_helper file accordingly.

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # allow test data to persist between transactions
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

That is the brute force approach. While it is understandable for the UI end-to-end tests, it is not a good idea for unit tests.  This is because you want unit tests to be done in a random, isolated way that does not depend on a particular state in the database.

One good approach is to conditionally set transactional fixtures on or off depending on the type of test running.

Here's an article on the topic: https://weilu.github.io/blog/2012/11/10/conditionally-switching-off-transactional-fixtures/

If you want to disable transactional fixtures for just one test you can switch it off in the describe block:

```
describe "YourAwesomeFeature" do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like the transactional fixtures setting will allow the things we create with Factory Girl to persist across many tests, but will Factory Girl still undo everything it did at the end? I need it to not do that - it has to leave everything it created, permanently, and let it be accessible to anyone interacting with the system after the rspec test has finished. Is that what Database Cleaner does, and if I simply don't have it #clean, will it leave everything in the DB permanently?

Comment: FactoryGirl does not delete anything.  Think of it as literally being a "factory" that generates objects.  If you are not doing any unit testing and your one and only use case is to have objects persist in the database, turning `transactional_fixtures` off should work fine.  No need to use Database Cleaner.

Comment: Cool. There is unit testing being done, but I don't think there will be any issues with that. Developers will be writing unit and other tests using Factory Girl that will generate whatever data they need and make no specific assumptions about other data in the db. Those tests should create/destroy their own data in their own little bubble. The intent with my tests is to highjack that functionality and invoke specific, special "tests" that will actually just be utilities for creating test data. Those tests will exit, and then I'll run my UI test using the data they created.

Comment: Sounds like you may not want to turn off transactional fixtures globally.  Since your UI test is singular, you may just want to disable transactional fixtures within the `describe` block.  See my updated answer.

Comment: If my answer works for your use case, please mark accept this answer for other's future reference.